# partially update fields in a document - findAndModify remove all other fields?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

When using MongoTemplate - collection.findAndModify It will delete all document fields, and leave only the updated column/s.

Why is that? 

How to partially update fields in a document?

```
        DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("company");           
        DBObject query= new BasicDBObject("companyId","1");        
        DBObject update= new BasicDBObject("phoneNumber","404-525-3928");           
        DBObject result = collection.findAndModify(query, update);
```

At this point - all fields removed from  company 1...

The workaround will be to go to the DB, fetch company 1 document update the field/s and save it..., 

But what if i need to update 10K of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in the update document. You use that and other [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) here otherwise what you specify **will replace** whatever the document currently contains:

```
        DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("company");           
        DBObject query= new BasicDBObject("companyId","1");        
        DBObject update= new BasicDBObject(
            "$set", new BasicDBObject("phoneNumber","404-525-3928")
        );          
        DBObject result = collection.findAndModify(query, update);
```

Comment: working great thank you!                                      I used collection.update(query,new BasicDBObject(
            "$set", new BasicDBObject("phoneNumber","404-525-3928"))